# Using Craft Prune - convert JSON Array of Objects to simple array

Tags: javascript, array, json

I am using the Craft Prune plugin (https://github.com/mattstauffer/craftcms-prune) to pull out a JSON array of entries from a section of my site with the aim of integrating the data into a typeahead search field as autocomplete data.

The problem I seem to be having is that the JSON array structure needs to be simplified for use as a datasource with typeahead.

So the current JSON data structure is:

```
[{"title":"Entry One Title"}, {"title":"Entry Two Title"}, {"title":"Entry Three Title"}]
```

What I actually need the structure to be is:

```
["Entry One Title", "Entry Two Title", "Entry Three Title"]
```

I have already tried using the jQuery $.each() function and the jQuery $.map() function but they both simply return an array of objects not a simple JS array.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up working out a solution:

```
var myData = {{ craft.entries.section('sectionName').find() | prune(['title']) | json_encode() | raw  }};
    var myArray = $.makeArray(myData);
    var newArray = new Array();
    $.each( arr, function(key, value) {
        $.each(value, function(keyNew, valueNew){
            newArray.push(valueNew);
        });
    });
```